# How to forward a request from one particular port to another with Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have request that is `http://localhost/services/pdf/module/generate/` to

```
http://localhost:8080/services/pdf/module/generate/
```

What to write in `httpd.conf` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below redirect rule to forward request from particular port to another Apache httpd. You can adjust port as per your requirement.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/$1 [L,R]
```